# Google beacon dashboard - Issue with NearBy notifications

Tags: android, eddystone, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I am trying to use beacons in my project. Facing some issue with it.

I have registered one beacon with google in my project using BeaconTools app and gave access using Proximity Beacon API IAM dashboard to myself to use it in another project as well.

I am getting NearBy notification only for WebURL. I tried using it for AppIntent and FreeFormAppIntent using beacon dashboard but I am not getting the nearby notification from a beacon.

- Do I have to use EDDYSTONE URL for sending APPINTENT and FREEFORMAPPINTENT nearby notification?
- Do I have to register separate beacon to get a NearBy notification in my other project? I am asking this because as we get an option to set ATTACHMENT in another project we don't get in NearBy notification section. If I am not wrong then PROJECT LIST is not necessary for NearBy notification as we set LANGUAGE CODE to define on which device we have to send the notification.
- I am using google nearby API but my app is not listed in Google--->NearBy--->UsingNearBy section. How to find out the solution what's wrong?

Comment: Can you post the intent you are trying to use? The problem may have to do with the formatting of the intent.